# Could not create output file

Tags: delphi, fatal-error

When i run my RAD Studio 11 Delphi project i get a fata-error.
**[dcc32 Fatal Error] F2039 Could not create output file '.\Win32\Debug\Project1.exe'**
Is this due to my project having more than one form? Currently to fix the problem i have to restart my computer but then running my program only works once then i get a fatal error again.
I have also tried running RAD Studio as administrator but it does not seem to work.
All my vcl forms are in the same folder so that should not be a problem. I also took a way the vcl forms and the error still happened.

Comment: I expect your application is not exiting when you close it. You need to use a debugger to find out why. Might also help to create a test application that recreates the basics of what you're doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you don't close the application you launched.

RAD Studio cannot overwrite the .exe file of your program because it is still running in your OS. Windows locks running executable files against write access.

Comment: Or it could be [Microsoft Defender Exploit Guard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70438545/4299358) on Windows 10.